# SVG icon for google maps polyline not rendering correctly

Tags: javascript, google-maps, svg, google-maps-api-3

I use google maps polylines to draw oriented icons according to path on the map.
The problem is that some of that are not rendered correctly and I'm not able to understand what is the problem.

**here's the code**

```
<script>
var minZoomLevel = 17;
var maxZoomLevel = 19;

function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 17,
    mapTypeId: 'terrain',
    mapTypeControl: false,
    styles: [{featureType: "poi", elementType: "labels", stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }]}, {featureType: "landscape", stylers: [{ visibility: "simplified"}]}],
    streetViewControl: false,
    center: segn
});

var iconSymbol1_1 = { //zoom 17 blue
        path: 'M 0 0 L 40 0 L 40 60 L 0 60 Z',
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(20, 0),
        scale: 0.10,
        strokeColor: '#000000',
        strokeWeight: 1,
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        fillColor: 'steelblue',
        fillOpacity: 0.8,
    };
var iconSymbol1_2 = { //zoom 17 red
        path: 'M 0 0 L 40 0 L 40 60 L 0 60 Z',
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(20, 0),
        scale: 0.10,
        strokeColor: '#000000',
        strokeWeight: 1,
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        fillColor: '#ff0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.8,
    };
var iconSymbol2_1 = { //zoom 18 blue
        path: 'M 0 0 L 40 0 L 40 60 L 0 60 Z',
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(20, 0),
        scale: 0.20,
        strokeColor: '#000000',
        strokeWeight: 1,
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        fillColor: 'steelblue',
        fillOpacity: 0.8,
    };
var iconSymbol2_2 = { //zoom 18 red
        path: 'M 0 0 L 40 0 L 40 60 L 0 60 Z',
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(20, 0),
        scale: 0.20,
        strokeColor: '#000000',
        strokeWeight: 1,
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        fillColor: '#ff0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.8,
    };
var iconSymbol3_1 = { //zoom 19 blue
        path: 'M 0 0 L 35 0 L 35 56 L 0 56 Z',
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(20, 0),
        scale: 0.40,
        strokeColor: '#000000',
        strokeWeight: 1,
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        fillColor: 'steelblue',
        fillOpacity: 0.8,
    };
var iconSymbol3_2 = { //zoom 19 red
        path: 'M 0 0 L 35 0 L 35 56 L 0 56 Z',
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(20, 0),
        scale: 0.40,
        strokeColor: '#000000',
        strokeWeight: 1,
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        fillColor: '#ff0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.8,
    };



var sensorePath0 = [];
                sensorePath0.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.81849, 14.34015));
                sensorePath0.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.8184636, 14.3401007));
            var polyOpts0 = {
                map: map,
                path: sensorePath0,
                icons: [{
                    icon: iconSymbol1_1
                }],
                strokeColor: '#000000',
                strokeWeight: 12,
                strokeOpacity: 0.0
            }
            polyline0 = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOpts0);

        var sensorePath1 = [];
                sensorePath1.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.8184636, 14.3401007));
                sensorePath1.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.8184371, 14.3400514));
            var polyOpts1 = {
                map: map,
                path: sensorePath1,
                icons: [{
                    icon: iconSymbol1_1
                }],
                strokeColor: '#000000',
                strokeWeight: 12,
                strokeOpacity: 0.0
            }
            polyline1 = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOpts1);

        var sensorePath2 = [];
                sensorePath2.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.8184371, 14.3400514));
                sensorePath2.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.8184107, 14.3400021));
            var polyOpts2 = {
                map: map,
                path: sensorePath2,
                icons: [{
                    icon: iconSymbol1_1
                }],
                strokeColor: '#000000',
                strokeWeight: 12,
                strokeOpacity: 0.0
            }
            polyline2 = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOpts2);

        polyline2.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol1_2 }] });var sensorePath3 = [];
                sensorePath3.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.8184107, 14.3400021));
                sensorePath3.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.8183843, 14.3399529));
            var polyOpts3 = {
                map: map,
                path: sensorePath3,
                icons: [{
                    icon: iconSymbol1_1
                }],
                strokeColor: '#000000',
                strokeWeight: 12,
                strokeOpacity: 0.0
            }
            polyline3 = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOpts3);

        var sensorePath4 = [];
                sensorePath4.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.8183843, 14.3399529));
                sensorePath4.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.8183579, 14.3399036));
            var polyOpts4 = {
                map: map,
                path: sensorePath4,
                icons: [{
                    icon: iconSymbol1_1
                }],
                strokeColor: '#000000',
                strokeWeight: 12,
                strokeOpacity: 0.0
            }
            polyline4 = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOpts4);

        var sensorePath5 = [];
                sensorePath5.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.8183579, 14.3399036));
                sensorePath5.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.8183314, 14.3398543));
            var polyOpts5 = {
                map: map,
                path: sensorePath5,
                icons: [{
                    icon: iconSymbol1_1
                }],
                strokeColor: '#000000',
                strokeWeight: 12,
                strokeOpacity: 0.0
            }
            polyline5 = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOpts5);

        var sensorePath6 = [];
                sensorePath6.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.8183314, 14.3398543));
                sensorePath6.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.818305, 14.339805));
            var polyOpts6 = {
                map: map,
                path: sensorePath6,
                icons: [{
                    icon: iconSymbol1_1
                }],
                strokeColor: '#000000',
                strokeWeight: 12,
                strokeOpacity: 0.0
            }
            polyline6 = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOpts6);

        var sensorePath7 = [];
                sensorePath7.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.818305, 14.339805));
                sensorePath7.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.8182786, 14.3397557));
            var polyOpts7 = {
                map: map,
                path: sensorePath7,
                icons: [{
                    icon: iconSymbol1_1
                }],
                strokeColor: '#000000',
                strokeWeight: 12,
                strokeOpacity: 0.0
            }
            polyline7 = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOpts7);

        var sensorePath8 = [];
                sensorePath8.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.8182786, 14.3397557));
                sensorePath8.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.8182521, 14.3397064));
            var polyOpts8 = {
                map: map,
                path: sensorePath8,
                icons: [{
                    icon: iconSymbol1_1
                }],
                strokeColor: '#000000',
                strokeWeight: 12,
                strokeOpacity: 0.0
            }
            polyline8 = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOpts8);

        var sensorePath9 = [];
                sensorePath9.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.8182521, 14.3397064));
                sensorePath9.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.8182257, 14.3396571));
            var polyOpts9 = {
                map: map,
                path: sensorePath9,
                icons: [{
                    icon: iconSymbol1_1
                }],
                strokeColor: '#000000',
                strokeWeight: 12,
                strokeOpacity: 0.0
            }
            polyline9 = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOpts9);

        var sensorePath10 = [];
                sensorePath10.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.8182257, 14.3396571));
                sensorePath10.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.8181993, 14.3396079));
            var polyOpts10 = {
                map: map,
                path: sensorePath10,
                icons: [{
                    icon: iconSymbol1_1
                }],
                strokeColor: '#000000',
                strokeWeight: 12,
                strokeOpacity: 0.0
            }
            polyline10 = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOpts10);

        var sensorePath11 = [];
                sensorePath11.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.8181993, 14.3396079));
                sensorePath11.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.8181729, 14.3395586));
            var polyOpts11 = {
                map: map,
                path: sensorePath11,
                icons: [{
                    icon: iconSymbol1_1
                }],
                strokeColor: '#000000',
                strokeWeight: 12,
                strokeOpacity: 0.0
            }
            polyline11 = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOpts11);

        var sensorePath12 = [];
                sensorePath12.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.8181729, 14.3395586));
                sensorePath12.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.8181464, 14.3395093));
            var polyOpts12 = {
                map: map,
                path: sensorePath12,
                icons: [{
                    icon: iconSymbol1_1
                }],
                strokeColor: '#000000',
                strokeWeight: 12,
                strokeOpacity: 0.0
            }
            polyline12 = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOpts12);

        var sensorePath13 = [];
                sensorePath13.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.8181464, 14.3395093));
                sensorePath13.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.81812, 14.33946));
            var polyOpts13 = {
                map: map,
                path: sensorePath13,
                icons: [{
                    icon: iconSymbol1_1
                }],
                strokeColor: '#000000',
                strokeWeight: 12,
                strokeOpacity: 0.0
            }
            polyline13 = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOpts13);

        var sensorePath14 = [];
                sensorePath14.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.81812, 14.33946));
                sensorePath14.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.8180889, 14.3394144));
            var polyOpts14 = {
                map: map,
                path: sensorePath14,
                icons: [{
                    icon: iconSymbol1_1
                }],
                strokeColor: '#000000',
                strokeWeight: 12,
                strokeOpacity: 0.0
            }
            polyline14 = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOpts14);

        var sensorePath15 = [];
                sensorePath15.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.8180889, 14.3394144));
                sensorePath15.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.8180578, 14.3393689));
            var polyOpts15 = {
                map: map,
                path: sensorePath15,
                icons: [{
                    icon: iconSymbol1_1
                }],
                strokeColor: '#000000',
                strokeWeight: 12,
                strokeOpacity: 0.0
            }
            polyline15 = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOpts15);

        var sensorePath16 = [];
                sensorePath16.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.8180578, 14.3393689));
                sensorePath16.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.8180267, 14.3393233));
            var polyOpts16 = {
                map: map,
                path: sensorePath16,
                icons: [{
                    icon: iconSymbol1_1
                }],
                strokeColor: '#000000',
                strokeWeight: 12,
                strokeOpacity: 0.0
            }
            polyline16 = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOpts16);

        var sensorePath17 = [];
                sensorePath17.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.8180267, 14.3393233));
                sensorePath17.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.8179956, 14.3392778));
            var polyOpts17 = {
                map: map,
                path: sensorePath17,
                icons: [{
                    icon: iconSymbol1_1
                }],
                strokeColor: '#000000',
                strokeWeight: 12,
                strokeOpacity: 0.0
            }
            polyline17 = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOpts17);

        var sensorePath18 = [];
                sensorePath18.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.8179956, 14.3392778));
                sensorePath18.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.8179644, 14.3392322));
            var polyOpts18 = {
                map: map,
                path: sensorePath18,
                icons: [{
                    icon: iconSymbol1_1
                }],
                strokeColor: '#000000',
                strokeWeight: 12,
                strokeOpacity: 0.0
            }
            polyline18 = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOpts18);

        var sensorePath19 = [];
                sensorePath19.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.8179644, 14.3392322));
                sensorePath19.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.8179333, 14.3391867));
            var polyOpts19 = {
                map: map,
                path: sensorePath19,
                icons: [{
                    icon: iconSymbol1_1
                }],
                strokeColor: '#000000',
                strokeWeight: 12,
                strokeOpacity: 0.0
            }
            polyline19 = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOpts19);

        var sensorePath20 = [];
                sensorePath20.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.8179333, 14.3391867));
                sensorePath20.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.8179022, 14.3391411));
            var polyOpts20 = {
                map: map,
                path: sensorePath20,
                icons: [{
                    icon: iconSymbol1_1
                }],
                strokeColor: '#000000',
                strokeWeight: 12,
                strokeOpacity: 0.0
            }
            polyline20 = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOpts20);

        var sensorePath21 = [];
                sensorePath21.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.8179022, 14.3391411));
                sensorePath21.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.8178711, 14.3390956));
            var polyOpts21 = {
                map: map,
                path: sensorePath21,
                icons: [{
                    icon: iconSymbol1_1
                }],
                strokeColor: '#000000',
                strokeWeight: 12,
                strokeOpacity: 0.0
            }
            polyline21 = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOpts21);

        var sensorePath22 = [];
                sensorePath22.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.8178711, 14.3390956));
                sensorePath22.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.81784, 14.33905));
            var polyOpts22 = {
                map: map,
                path: sensorePath22,
                icons: [{
                    icon: iconSymbol1_1
                }],
                strokeColor: '#000000',
                strokeWeight: 12,
                strokeOpacity: 0.0
            }
            polyline22 = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOpts22);

        var sensorePath23 = [];
                sensorePath23.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.81757, 14.34131));
                sensorePath23.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.8175367, 14.3412683));
            var polyOpts23 = {
                map: map,
                path: sensorePath23,
                icons: [{
                    icon: iconSymbol1_1
                }],
                strokeColor: '#000000',
                strokeWeight: 12,
                strokeOpacity: 0.0
            }
            polyline23 = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOpts23);

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
     var zoom = map.getZoom();

    if (map.getZoom() < minZoomLevel) map.setZoom(minZoomLevel);
    else if (map.getZoom() > maxZoomLevel) map.setZoom(maxZoomLevel);

    switch(zoom){
    case 17:
    polyline0.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol1_1 }] });
        polyline1.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol1_1 }] });
        polyline2.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol1_2 }] });
        polyline3.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol1_1 }] });
        polyline4.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol1_1 }] });
        polyline5.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol1_1 }] });
        polyline6.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol1_1 }] });
        polyline7.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol1_1 }] });
        polyline8.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol1_1 }] });
        polyline9.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol1_1 }] });
        polyline10.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol1_1 }] });
        polyline11.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol1_1 }] });
        polyline12.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol1_1 }] });
        polyline13.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol1_1 }] });
        polyline14.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol1_1 }] });
        polyline15.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol1_1 }] });
        polyline16.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol1_1 }] });
        polyline17.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol1_1 }] });
        polyline18.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol1_1 }] });
        polyline19.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol1_1 }] });
        polyline20.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol1_1 }] });
        polyline21.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol1_1 }] });
        polyline22.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol1_1 }] });
        polyline23.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol1_1 }] });
        break;
    case 18:
    polyline0.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol2_1 }] });
        polyline1.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol2_1 }] });
        polyline2.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol2_2 }] });
        polyline3.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol2_1 }] });
        polyline4.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol2_1 }] });
        polyline5.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol2_1 }] });
        polyline6.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol2_1 }] });
        polyline7.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol2_1 }] });
        polyline8.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol2_1 }] });
        polyline9.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol2_1 }] });
        polyline10.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol2_1 }] });
        polyline11.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol2_1 }] });
        polyline12.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol2_1 }] });
        polyline13.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol2_1 }] });
        polyline14.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol2_1 }] });
        polyline15.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol2_1 }] });
        polyline16.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol2_1 }] });
        polyline17.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol2_1 }] });
        polyline18.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol2_1 }] });
        polyline19.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol2_1 }] });
        polyline20.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol2_1 }] });
        polyline21.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol2_1 }] });
        polyline22.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol2_1 }] });
        polyline23.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol2_1 }] });
        break;
    case 19:
    polyline0.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol3_1 }] });
        polyline1.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol3_1 }] });
        polyline2.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol3_2 }] });
        polyline3.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol3_1 }] });
        polyline4.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol3_1 }] });
        polyline5.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol3_1 }] });
        polyline6.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol3_1 }] });
        polyline7.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol3_1 }] });
        polyline8.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol3_1 }] });
        polyline9.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol3_1 }] });
        polyline10.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol3_1 }] });
        polyline11.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol3_1 }] });
        polyline12.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol3_1 }] });
        polyline13.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol3_1 }] });
        polyline14.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol3_1 }] });
        polyline15.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol3_1 }] });
        polyline16.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol3_1 }] });
        polyline17.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol3_1 }] });
        polyline18.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol3_1 }] });
        polyline19.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol3_1 }] });
        polyline20.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol3_1 }] });
        polyline21.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol3_1 }] });
        polyline22.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol3_1 }] });
        polyline23.setOptions({icons: [{ icon: iconSymbol3_1 }] });
        break;
    }
});
}
```

As you can see, I use different icons for different zoom levels. My problem shows up with 19 zoom level.

This is an example of svg icons non correctly rendered:

[svg not rendered correctly - zoom level 19](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyXDG.png)

This is an example of svg icons correctly rendered at different zoom level:

[svg rendered correctly - zoom level 18](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OGox.png)

If you want to better understand the code, this is another question (SOLVED) where it's explained. 
I make another question beacuse they are two different issues.
[Question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40911099/draw-particular-elements-on-a-map)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: ok. i removed some part of code that was irrelevant for my issue. You can see it in the first image that I posted. Can you see that some rectangles are not rendered correctly?

Comment: I can't run your PHP (or your image).  It would be more useful to post a [mcve] with the code that is rendered in the browser that exhibits the problem.

Comment: ok. I removed the php code and I post just the code rendered. I posted some pctures where you can see the problem

Answer (score 0):

Each zoom level is different by a factor of 2.  The scale should change by a factor of 2 (for zoom level 19 `scale: 0.35` should be `scale: 0.4`)

Comment: Do you think that's the problem? The size of objects for each zoom level is correct. The issue is that some of them are randomly cutted. So I cannot understand why that happen